# Gem:loaderror when the new Rails project is made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I used to use Rails4  and updated everything to Rails5. Since then, I've been getting gem:loaderror whenever i make a new rails project.

I type `rails new sampletest`.

After the project automatically installs gems, I get an error saying,

```
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Users/(folder)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:322:in `block in replace_gem': spring is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/(folder)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spring:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/(folder)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/(folder)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why it is saying I should put "spring" to the gemfile when it is there.

Comment: it says that gems in the groups development and test were not installed. and `spring` is usually is added in development group. so try to install them by running `bundle install`

Comment: Even if I re-run `bundle install`, it is kept saying `Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.`. Can you guess why?

Comment: can you run `bundle config` and post the output?

Comment: without
Set for your local app (/Users/(folder_name)/Developer/Web-App/rails-tutorial-hartl/bundlertest/.bundle/config): "development:test"
Set for the current user (/Users/(folder_name)/.bundle/config): "development:test"

Comment: as you can you have global setting for skipping development and test. you can manually edit `/Users/(folder_name)/.bundle/config` and remove those lines.

Comment: Do you know how to change the setting globally not just in local app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124063/discussion-between-aleksey-and-johksi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have problems with bundler config.
You can run `bundle config` to see what it looks like.

It your case you have

```
$ bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
without
Set for the current user (/Users/(folder_name)/.bundle/config): "development test"
...
```

So you have global setting.
You should edit `/Users/(folder_name)/.bundle/config` by removing without statement.
You can run `bundle config --delete without` to do it.

Then you can run `bundle config` once again.
In your particular case you see

```
Set for your local app (/home/aleksey/projects/mercury/.bundle/config): "development test"
...
```

So you have local `without` setting too.
Remove it by running `bundle config --delete without` once again.

Now you are ready to run `bundle install`. All gems should be installed this time.